# ReactJS and PHP Sessions

Tags: php, reactjs

I am attempting to change my front end of my website to use ReactJS. I can connect to my PHP script just fine using ReactJS fetch command. However, when I do this, PHP Sessions no longer seem to work. Do PHP sessions not work with ReactJS (or Javascript in general)? If not, why not?

How do I fix this?

Comment: `fetch` has nothing to do with React.

Comment: Thank you! This helped solve my problem. I did not realize it was related to the `fetch` command itself.